# gridview delete and select not working (with datakeynames)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I have a gridview filled with data from an objectdatasource. In that objectdatasource I have also specefied my delete and selectmethods. But, for some reason the delete and select don't work (or I get the error *Data keys must be specified on GridView 'GridView1' before the selected data keys can be retrieved.  Use the DataKeyNames property to specify data keys.*, or it just doesn't do anything). This would imply the datakeyname isn't set or wrong, but it is set (and by my knowledge it's correct)?

I'm working with BO and DAL classes.

BO:

```
    public int OrderID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set { _ID = value; }
    }
```

DAL (delete), if i get the delete, I will try to figure out the select myself again.

```
[DataObjectMethodAttribute(DataObjectMethodType.Delete, true)]
    public static int DeleteOrder(Int32 OrderID)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

        string sql =
          "DELETE FROM tblOrders WHERE ID=@OrderID";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", OrderID);

        conn.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        return i;
    }
```

aspx (gridview):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="OrderID" DataSourceID="dtsrcOrder" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
      EnableViewState="False" CssClass="gv" GridLines="None" Height="63px" Width="527px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">
          <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="OrderID"></asp:BoundField>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderNAME" HeaderText="Naam" SortExpression="OrderNAME"></asp:BoundField>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderBOOK_ID" HeaderText="Boek" SortExpression="OrderBOOK_ID"></asp:BoundField>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderCOUNT" HeaderText="Aantal" SortExpression="OrderCOUNT"></asp:BoundField>
              <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="OrderPAID" HeaderText="Betaald" SortExpression="OrderPAID"></asp:CheckBoxField>

              <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
          </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```

aspx objectdatasource:

```
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dtsrcOrder" runat="server" DeleteMethod="DeleteOrder" SelectMethod="GetOrdersbyID" TypeName="DAL.OrdersDAL"
        DataObjectTypeName="BO.Order">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="OrderID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
        </DeleteParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="OrderID" Type="Int32"></asp:ControlParameter>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Can somebody spot my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement contains a syntax error:

```
string sql = "DELETE FROM tblOrders WHERE ID=@OrderID";
```

try:

```
sql = "DELETE tblOrders WHERE ID=@OrderID";
```

Also, you may try to use `SQL DataSource` instead of `Object DataSource` to simplify your solution. Hope this may help.